# Can I develope a dynamic GUI with glade?

Tags: gtk, glade

This is a newbie question so forgive me but I'm confused.

Suppose, as a simple example, that I wish to have a GUI that has a button to add some component (say a file chooser widget) to the interface as many times as I want. (and maybe another button to remove the last if you wish to think more pragmatically). How would I design such a thing using glade? Is there any way to have the buttons "working" inside glade itself?

My guess is that I can only design the default interface and then I am manually responsible for the callbacks that will add and remove components. My GUI will however be static from within glade so I can only test it during runtime. Is that the basic idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct, there is no way to test the callbacks in glade itself and you can only test it during runtime.